# scalebox and equations

Tags: equations, resize

I have a big diagram (that I produce with \xymatrix) that I want to rescale to fit the page. Currently, I am using

```
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\[\xymatrix{
bigdiagram
}\]
}
```

and it produces what I want but I get the error

```
LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.2366 }
```

everytime I compile my tex file. What is the proper way to resizing an equation?

Comment: Instead of `\[...\]`, try with `$...$`.

Comment: … or, perhaps better, with `\(\displaystyle ...\)` (or `$\displaystyle ...$`, for that matter).

Comment: Could you post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/69818)?  It would be interesting to see the code for the `bigdiagram`, too: perhaps somebody would be able to suggest you a better solution than simply (and crudely) scaling it down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see essentially two sources of trouble:

1. LaTeX allows “Display math mode”, which is the math mode implied
   by the `\[...\]` syntax, only inside the so-called “paragraph mode”
   (the name was chosen by Leslie Lamport himself), which is, roughly
   speaking, the mode LaTeX is in when it is typesetting ordinary paragraphs.
   Unfortunately, the main argument of a `\resizebox` command is typeset
   in a different mode (Lamport calls it “left-to-right mode”, or “LR mode”
   for short), that does not allow displayed equations.  See p. 36 of the
   2nd edition of Lamport’s manual
   (L. Lamport, *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System*, second edition)
   for more information.
2. If your `bigdiagram` is typeset using an environment that needs to change
   `\catcode`s, like the `tikzcd` environment defined by the `tikz-cd` package,
   than (usually) you cannot put it inside the argument of another command.
   It seems, though, that you are using the `xy` (Xy-Pic) package:
   I cannot
   recollect for sure, off the top of my head, that this environment too
   needs to change `\catcode`s (I used the Xy-Pic package some twenty years
   ago, and only sometimes), but it’s very likely it does, hence suffering
   from the same problem.

You can obviate the first problem by substituting in-line math mode for display math mode, possibly using `\displaystyle` to get symbols in the same size as if they were displayed, as in the following code excerpt:

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} + \frac{y}{2} = z\)%
}
```

To circumvent the second, you can use the `lrbox` environment to save the typeset diagram in a temporary storage box, and than use that box in the argument of `\resizebox`, as in

```
\newsavebox{\tempDiagram}
\begin{lrbox}{\tempDiagram}
    \( % "\displaystyle" doesn't matter in this case
        \begin{tikzcd} % example taken from the "tikz-cd" manual
            A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r,"\phi"] & B \\
                                          & C
        \end{tikzcd}
    \)
\end{lrbox}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\tempDiagram}}
```

Full MWE:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath} % compatibility check
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}



\begin{document}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} + \frac{y}{2} = z\)%
}

\newsavebox{\tempDiagram}
\begin{lrbox}{\tempDiagram}
    \( % "\displaystyle" doesn't matter in this case
        \begin{tikzcd} % example taken from the "tikz-cd" manual
            A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r,"\phi"] & B \\
                                          & C
        \end{tikzcd}
    \)
\end{lrbox}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{\tempDiagram}}

\end{document}
```

The picture below shows the full page I get in the output file.  For the record, I’m now working on my backup computer, which, unfortunately, is only equipped with the 2016 release of TeXLive; but this shouldn’t have any substantial impact on the output produced.  On the other hand, it looks like my installation lacks several fonts that the Xy-Pic package needs to do its job, so I’m not able to experiment with it… :-(

[image: Output of the above MWE]

Two final remarks:

1. I recommend that you consider switching to
   the `tikz-cd` package for typesetting your diagrams.
2. As you can see, scaling (up or) down a whole math formula
   can look awful, since the typafaces are scaled too,
   and in practice it’s a viable solution only if the scaling
   factor is very close to one; otherwise, you should try really
   hard to find a different solution.

Comment: The first solution already worked for my example. Thank you!